# How to Retrive all fields after getting acess token in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get all the fields after getting the access-token?
I am not able to get all the fields but age,email,name and id.
If i am passing work,education in parameters then nothing is displaying
please help me out.

```
"access_token":"...","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5162400}



https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=EAADZArmkJ5zkBAHdxtYQZB65vWgS7p8ALFel1bjJ8ihi0e4JKi3BincGNxuOB9evD7KkZBAIwzMjIZCJfdZBoABU7B27rntytYHI6d8FPpvLLSQT4OxtNwEa6RRpmcMQBSikIwObrIXa33oeZC91rl9q7mFRlbw3jvq1QOrWWa9QZDZD&fields=name,gender,email,relationship_status,link,timezone,currency,work
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEVER post Access Tokens on Stackoverflow.

That being said, the debugger says that you only authorized the user with the email permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

For other fields, you may need additional permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Comment: Thanks for your reply.what kind of permission i need to get all  fields?

Comment: How to set permission.?   I had tried this  in the end of url  @scope=user_work_history but didnt get the work informations yet

Comment: check out the link to the permission list. you can´t just get "all fields", you need to decide which ones you need and authorize with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: use the debug link to debug your token and see if the permission is authorized correctly.

Comment: i am getting profile pic url but i want to get photo ?

Comment: I am getting profile pic link.but i want to display the photo instead of link..so is there any way? and yes i already checked

Comment: what exactly do you get? what link exactly? how about <img src="photo-link" /> ?

Comment: i am using salesforce and want to display on vf page with static resource.

Comment: that was not my question...if you get a link, just use php curl to download the photo, for example.